# Storing selected spinner item in database table - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, spinner

So my situation is this. I have two tables. A main table where data is added using a form, this form has a spinner which is powered from the second table (this part is working correctly). I then want the selected item in the spinner to be stored in a foreignkey field in the main table.

I have been using the following code:

```
private Spinner mSpinner;

mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinCat);
```

and in my populate fields method I have the following:

```
  mSpinner.getSelectedItem();
```

but this stores something like "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43e5be60" in to the database rather than the name.

If anyone can offer some help it would be great, this has been bothering me for some days now and has halted development somewhat. If you need to see more code, then please don't hesitate to ask.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: new code:

```
            mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View vw,
                    int pos, long id) {
                LinearLayout rowll = (LinearLayout) vw;
                TextView test = (TextView) rowll.getChildAt(0);
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), test
                        .getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // Do nothing..
            }
        });
```

Comment: How did you listed values in spinner by using String Array or something else?

Comment: These are taken from a database table using a cursor with a method to fetch all of the information to fill the spinner with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSelectedItem` returns an `Object` (which is what your output looks a lot like).

Did you try simply calling toString like this?

```
mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

I personally just set a variable in the onItemSelected listener, but this should work too. What I use is:

```
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            myIP = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }
```

Variable is then continuously updated and I just add it to the DB when I connect to the IP in question.

Cursor data extraction:

```
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        ipList.add(cursor.getString(1));
    }
```

`getString(int columnIndex)` does: Returns the value of the requested column as a String.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

Comment: What would this be overriding? sorry for my stupidity - still learning the ropes when it comes to java/android - thanks for the help so far!EDIT: adding toString results in the same problem.

Comment: Hmmm...you're still handling the Cursor? Have you done anything to extract the values from the Cursor? I'm not really sure how far you are so not sure where to help you. Does the data display correctly in the Spinner? I guess I misunderstood how far you are.

Comment: Yep, the spinner is populated ok - I will put the code for this in to my main post.

Comment: Especially the part where you handle the Cursor

Comment: Code is added now, let me know if anything further is required - thanks a lot for the assistance.

Comment: There's no actual handling of the cursor there? You need to extract values using `Cursor.moveToNext();` (a while loop works well since it returns true as long as there's more data to gather). Regardless though, I think you should try to simply create a variable and change it like I do on the listener. Do spinner.Add setOnItemSelectedListener and Eclipse will give you the 2 methods. I'm running out of time right now, sorry!

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused by what you mean - do you have any code example or anything fromt he developer docs you could link me to? really appreciated the help.

Comment: I put it in the original answer. Don't worry about it - anyway, gotta jet for an hour! I can give it more time later, just in a rush now. ;)

Comment: I have implemented similar before from an example but without the while loop and I still go the same results - where does the while loop go?

Comment: I've added some code which seems to almost work and it toasts the correct thing when selecting it, but it's still not putting it in to the database correct.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use .getChildAt(), use .getItemAtPositon(). See how the code does it at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html.